# Is there any way to call a function in a module B, and B module is inside A module just importing module A?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we Have in python 3+

```
import OpenGL as gl
```

and I want to do something as

```
gl.GL.glClearColor(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
```

this doesn't work, but I'm curious to know if there is any way to do that, just import the main module and call other from the main.

```
import pygame as pg
from OpenGL import GL as gl
from OpenGL.GL import shaders as gls

import numpy as np
import ctypes

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        #initialise pygame
        pg.init()
        pg.display.set_mode((640,480), pg.OPENGL|pg.DOUBLEBUF)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        #initialise opengl
        gl.glClearColor(0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1)
        self.shader = self.createShader("shaders/vertex.txt", "shaders/fragment.txt")
        self.triangle = Triangle(self.shader)
        self.mainLoop()
    
    def createShader(self, vertexFilepath, fragmentFilepath):

        with open(vertexFilepath,'r') as f:
            vertex_src = f.readlines()

        with open(fragmentFilepath,'r') as f:
            fragment_src = f.readlines()
        
        shader = gls.compileProgram(gls.compileShader(vertex_src, gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                gls.compileShader(fragment_src, gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
        
        return shader

    def mainLoop(self):
        running = True
        while (running):
            #check events
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if (event.type == pg.QUIT):
                    running = False
            #refresh screen
            gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            self.triangle.draw(self.shader)
            pg.display.flip()

            #timing
            self.clock.tick()
            framerate = int(self.clock.get_fps())
            pg.display.set_caption(f"Running at {framerate} fps.")
        self.quit()

    def quit(self):
        self.triangle.destroy()
        gl.glDeleteProgram(self.shader)
        pg.quit()

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, shader):
        gl.glUseProgram(shader)
        # x, y, z, r, g, b
        self.vertices = (
            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             0.0,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        )
        self.vertices = np.array(self.vertices, dtype=np.float32)

        self.vertex_count = 3

        self.vao = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
        gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        self.vbo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertices.nbytes, self.vertices, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
        
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, gl.GL_FLOAT, gl.GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

    def draw(self, shader):
        gl.glUseProgram(shader)
        gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.vertex_count)

    def destroy(self):
        gl.glDeleteVertexArrays(1,(self.vao,))
        gl.glDeleteBuffers(1,(self.vbo,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

But I want to replace "from OpenGL import GL as gl" and "from OpenGL.GL import shaders as gls" to just one *import* something as import OpenGL as gl, and from gl I want to access the sub-modules and functions inside it using a complete path, something as gl.GL.shaders.compileShader(). Is there any way to do it in python?
If i try do this using complete path I got this error

> AttributeError: module 'OpenGL.GL' has no attribute 'GL'

Comment: Hi Angelo, welcome to the site. Its not clear to me from your question what exactly you're asking about. Can you clarify what is going wrong with the import and function call you show? What is the error you're getting? Or if you're not getting an error directly, what is it doing wrong?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).